# MySQL - Why query with 'IN' fails?

Tags: mysql, error-handling

These queries return correct results:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `users`
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `teachers`
```

But this one generates an error

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN  ('users', 'teachers')
```

I have tried single quote, double quote, back-quote and no quote and all fail. What am I doing wrong?

The error is this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '('users', 'teachers')' at line 1
```

Comment: Is that actually valid syntax for a `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` query? It might not be.

Comment: This is from the manual: `SHOW [FULL] COLUMNS {FROM | IN} tbl_name [{FROM | IN} db_name] [LIKE 'pattern']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this gives you what you're after?

```
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name IN ('users', 'teachers')
```

Comment: Ooh, an SQL wizard has appeared :) +1 for skipping over the asked question to the one that actually matters

Answer (score 2):

According to the MySQL docs ([section 12.4.5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-columns.html)), you can use the keyword `IN` instead of `FROM`, but it doesn't have the same meaning as in a `WHERE` clause; it's just a synonym for `FROM` in this context.

```
SHOW [FULL] COLUMNS {FROM | IN} tbl_name [{FROM | IN} db_name] [LIKE 'pattern']
```

`{FROM | IN}` signifies that the two are interchangable. The fact it doesn't say something like `{FROM tbl_name | IN (tbl_name1, tbl_name2, ...)}` means that there is no difference between the two.

I'm not sure that showing more than one table's columns is doable in one simple query. Maybe subqueries would do the trick? (Not an SQL wizard, but there are some around here.)

Comment: @ Matchu - Thank you. Is it documented somewhere, that the meaning of `IN` here differs from its usual meaning? (if so I cannot see what use it could have)

Comment: @Majid — I think it's just aesthetics. There are a number of spots in MySQL where certain keywords are equivalent, just because some people have different tastes. `SHOW COLUMNS IN users` definitely reads better as an English sentence, but `FROM` is more often used in MySQL. Meh. Trade-offs.